# Sort a Javascript Array by frequency and then filter repeats

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

What is an elegant way to take a javascript array, order by the frequency of the values, and then filter for uniques?

So,

`["apples", "oranges", "oranges", "oranges", "bananas", "bananas", "oranges"]`

becomes

`["oranges, "bananas", "apples"]`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Compute the frequency of each item first.

```
{
    apples: 1,
    oranges: 4,
    bananas: 2
}
```

Then create an array from this frequency object which will also remove the duplicates.

```
["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]
```

Now sort this array in descending order using the frequency map we created earlier.

```
function compareFrequency(a, b) {
    return frequency[b] - frequency[a];
}

array.sort(compareFrequency);
```

Here's the entire source (using the newly introduced [Array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/new_in_javascript_1.6#Array_extras) in ECMA 5) and combining the de-duplication and frequency map generation steps,

```
function sortByFrequency(array) {
    var frequency = {};

    array.forEach(function(value) { frequency[value] = 0; });

    var uniques = array.filter(function(value) {
        return ++frequency[value] == 1;
    });

    return uniques.sort(function(a, b) {
        return frequency[b] - frequency[a];
    });
}
```

Same as above using the regular array iteration.

```
function sortByFrequencyAndRemoveDuplicates(array) {
    var frequency = {}, value;

    // compute frequencies of each value
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        value = array[i];
        if(value in frequency) {
            frequency[value]++;
        }
        else {
            frequency[value] = 1;
        }
    }

    // make array from the frequency object to de-duplicate
    var uniques = [];
    for(value in frequency) {
        uniques.push(value);
    }

    // sort the uniques array in descending order by frequency
    function compareFrequency(a, b) {
        return frequency[b] - frequency[a];
    }

    return uniques.sort(compareFrequency);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

// returns most frequent to least frequent

```
Array.prototype.byCount= function(){
    var itm, a= [], L= this.length, o= {};
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        itm= this[i];
        if(!itm) continue;
        if(o[itm]== undefined) o[itm]= 1;
        else ++o[itm];
    }
    for(var p in o) a[a.length]= p;
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        return o[b]-o[a];
    });
}
```

//test

```
var A= ["apples","oranges","oranges","oranges","bananas","bananas","oranges"];
A.byCount()
```

/*  returned value: (Array)
oranges,bananas,apples
*/

Answer (score 3):

I was actually working on this at the same time - the solution I came up with is pretty much identical to Anurag's.

However I thought it might be worth sharing as I had a slightly different way of calculating the frequency of occurrences, using the ternary operator and checking if the value has been counted yet in a slightly different way.

```
function sortByFrequencyAndFilter(myArray)
{
    var newArray = [];
    var freq = {};

    //Count Frequency of Occurances
    var i=myArray.length-1;
    for (var i;i>-1;i--)
    {
        var value = myArray[i];
        freq[value]==null?freq[value]=1:freq[value]++;
    }

    //Create Array of Filtered Values
    for (var value in freq)
    {
        newArray.push(value);
    }

    //Define Sort Function and Return Sorted Results
    function compareFreq(a,b)
    {
        return freq[b]-freq[a];
    }

    return newArray.sort(compareFreq);
}
```

Comment: The loop I use to count for the frequency of occurrences checks against a constant value and loops through the array in reverse.  This would perform faster on large arrays as well.

Answer (score 1):

Basic strategy:

Create an object to use as a hash table to track the frequency of each item in the array to be sorted.

Create a new array containing the item, frequency pairs.

Sort this array on frequency in descending order.

Extract the items from that array.

Code:

```
function descendingUniqueSort(toBeSorted) {
    var hash = new Object();
    toBeSorted.forEach(function (element, index, array) { 
                           if (hash[element] == undefined) {
                               hash[element] = 1;
                           }
                           else {
                               hash[element] +=1;
                           }});
    var itemCounts = new Array();
    for (var key in hash) {
       var itemCount = new Object();
       itemCount.key = key;
       itemCount.count = hash[key];
       itemCounts.push(itemCount);
    }
    itemCounts.sort(function(a,b) { if(a.count<b.count) return 1; 
        else if (a.count>b.count) return -1; else return 0;});

    return itemCounts.map(function(itemCount) { return itemCount.key; });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ["apples", "oranges", "oranges", "oranges", "bananas", "bananas", "oranges"].sort();
var freq = {};
for (var s in arr) freq[s] = freq[s] ? freq[s] + 1 : 0;
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return freq[a] > freq[b] ? -1 : 1; });
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) arr.splice(i,1);
alert(arr.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

for the first step to compute

```
{
    oranges: 4,
    bananas: 2,
    apples: 1
}
```

you can use countBy function of underscroe.js

```
var all=["apples", "oranges", "oranges", "oranges", "bananas", "bananas", "oranges"];
var frequency=_.countBy(all,function(each){return each});
```

so `frequency` object will contain frequency of all unique values, and you can get an unique list by simply calling `_.uniq(all)`, and to sort that unique list by the `_.sortBy` method of underscore and using your `frequency` object you can use

```
_.sortBy(_.uniq(all),function(frequencyKey){return -frequency[frequencyKey]});
```

`-ve` sign is used here to sort the list in decending order by means of frequency value as per your requirement.

You can check the the documentation of [http://underscorejs.org/](http://Undersoce%20JS) for further optimization by your own trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me put a minimal code to get unique values (and with frequencies) in ES6.

```js
var arr = ["apples", "oranges", "oranges", "oranges", "bananas", "bananas", "oranges"];
console.log([...new Set(arr)])
console.log([...new Set(arr)].map(fruit=>({[fruit]:arr.filter(v=>(v===fruit)).length})))
```

It is also applied to array of objects to aggregate some properties.

```js
var arr = [{"fruit":"apples"}, {"fruit":"oranges"}, {"fruit":"oranges"}, {"fruit":"oranges"}, {"fruit":"bananas"}, {"fruit":"bananas"}, {"fruit":"oranges"}];
console.log(arr.reduce((x,y)=>{if(x[y.fruit]) {x[y.fruit]++;return x;} else {var z={};z[y.fruit]=1;return Object.assign(x,z);}},{}))
```

Comment: How does this give you frequencies? It only consolidates

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter of the array's elements using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
arr.reduce(
  (counter, key) => {counter[key] = 1 + counter[key] || 1; return counter}, 
  {}
);
```

Sort the counter object using `sort` on [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and finally show only keys.

```js
const arr = ["apples", "oranges", "oranges", "oranges",
  "bananas", "bananas", "oranges"
];

// create a counter object on array
let counter = arr.reduce(
  (counter, key) => {
    counter[key] = 1 + counter[key] || 1;
    return counter
  }, {});
console.log(counter);
// {"apples": 1, "oranges": 4, "bananas": 2}

// sort counter by values (compare position 1 entries)
// the result is an array
let sorted_counter = Object.entries(counter).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
console.log(sorted_counter);
// [["oranges", 4], ["bananas", 2], ["apples", 1]]

// show only keys of the sorted array
console.log(sorted_counter.map(x => x[0]));
// ["oranges", "bananas", "apples"]
```