# Return values from array and occurences by frequency

Tags: javascript, sorting, frequency

So i have this code

```
Array.prototype.byCount= function(){
    var itm, a= [], L= this.length, o= {};
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        itm= this[i];
        if(!itm) continue;
        if(o[itm]== undefined) o[itm]= 1;
        else ++o[itm];
    }
    for(var p in o) a[a.length]= p;
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        return o[b]-o[a];
    });
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579486/sort-a-javascript-array-by-frequency-and-then-filter-repeats)

This is almost what i need except that it does not return the number of occurences with the value.

I tried to rewrite it, but i always fail at the sorting part.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show us your attempt at rewriting it, then we'll be able to help you on the sorting part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Array.prototype.byCount= function(){
    var itm, a= [], L= this.length, o= {};
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        itm= this[i];
        if(!itm) continue;
        if(o[itm]== undefined) o[itm]= 1;
        else ++o[itm];
    }
    for(var p in o) a[a.length]= {item: p, frequency: o[p]};
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        return o[b.item]-o[a.item];
    });
}
```

Test:

```
var A= ["apples","oranges","oranges","oranges","bananas","bananas","oranges"];
A.byCount()
```

Produces:

```
[ { frequency: 4, item: "oranges" }, { frequency: 2, item: "bananas"}, {frequency: 1, item: "apples"} ]
```

**Edit**

Doing `return o[b.item]-o[a.item];` is completely overcomplicated an pointless as Bergi points out in comments. `return b.frequency - a.frequency;` would have been better.

Comment: That's unncessarily complicated.

Comment: That's almost certainly true. I spent the least effort possible modifying the existing code.

Comment: It is working, just one thing.
What should i do to remove all items that has the occurnce 1 before sorting process? Thanks

Comment: You could exclude them from the results `a` using `if (o[p] != 1)` before the   `a[a.length] =  ...`

Comment: `Array.prototype.byCount= function(){
    var itm, a= [], L= this.length, o= {};
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        itm= this[i];
        if(!itm) continue;
        if(o[itm]== undefined) o[itm]= 1;
        else ++o[itm];
    }
    for(var p in o) {
  if (o[p] != 1) {
   a[a.length]= {item: p, frequency: o[p]};
  }
 }
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        return o.frequency-o.frequency;
    });
}`

I added to the code, but now the sorting is not working.

Comment: that's because the sort function should be `b.frequency - a.frequency`

Comment: Sorry for being pain in the ass. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: RobH i want to hire you for a task, are you available for such a thing?

Comment: @user3210615 - no, thanks but I have a full time job already.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the frequencies and simplify the code a bit by doing the following:

```js
Array.prototype.byCount = function() {
  var o = {};

  this.filter(function(el) { return el; }).forEach(function(el) {
      o[el] = (o[el] || 0) + 1;
  });

  return Object.keys(o).map(function (key) {
      return { key: key, occurrences: o[key] };
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.occurrences - a.occurrences;
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify([1, 2, null, 9, 9, undefined, 9, 9, 1, 3, 1, 1, 9, 2].byCount()));
```

Result:

```
[{"key":"9","occurrences":5},
 {"key":"1","occurrences":4},
 {"key":"2","occurrences":2},
 {"key":"3","occurrences":1}]
```

If you have Lo-Dash available, you can do this a bit more cleanly:

```js
Array.prototype.byFreq = function () {
  var grouped = _.groupBy(_.compact(this)),
      pairs = _.map(grouped, function (vals, key) { 
          return { key: key, occurrences: vals.length }
      }),
      sorted = _.sortBy(pairs, function (pair) { 
          return -pair.occurrences 
      });
  return sorted;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,9,9, null, 9,9,1,3, undefined, 1,1,9,2].byFreq()));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the occurence counts to the values, you'd either put them together at the end:

```
return a.sort(function(a, b){
    return o[b]-o[a];
}).map(function(v) {
    return {value: v, count: o[v]}
});
```

or put them in the array right away and adapt the comparison function:

```
for (var p in o)
    a.push({value: p, count: o[p]});
return a.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.count-b.count;
});
```